# UltraVNC with Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, ultravnc

I'm having trouble getting UltraVNC to work correctly on Windows 7. I have version 1.0.9.6.2 which is the latest release. The problem I'm running into is using the "Remote Blank Monitor (on/off)" feature.

Here is my dilemma:
Computer "A" is running Windows 7 and computer "B" is running Windows 7, I connect to the remote computer "B", try to use this feature and all I get is a giant eyeball looking icon on both the viewing machine and the server machine.

If computer "A" is running Windows 7 or XP and computer "B" is running Windows XP, I connect into computer "B", try to use the feature and it works just fine.

I have tried to manipulate every setting on both machines to get it to work correctly, but can't figure it out. I have searched the forums on the UltraVNC site and can't get any help there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have a problem with the pseudo video driver of vnc.
Either vnc don't run as a service, either it hasn't been configured to use video hook (right-click on the vnc taskbar icon and choose properties). Or something similar.

Was your vnc installed while being logged as administrator ?

Comment: Yes I am logged on as administrator to the computers. I also manually downloaded the video hook drivers during the install process as well and there is a checkmark in the box. When I click on the "check video hook driver" it tells me "1.00.22 driver Not Active"

Comment: So I'm out of clue for this one. Hope someone else have a better idea.